# How to add .h and .so files to iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, video-streaming, rtsp

I have to make an app in Objective-C (iOS) for handle a stream video from an ip camera.
After lots of research I have not idea where to start :(
RTSP protocol is difficult thus i looked for a library and i
[found these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtxyG.png)

the site where i download it said that the library is for macOS.
I'd like to know if is possible add .so library to my xcode/iOS project, if so, how do it?

Or have you other solutions for RTSP stream in iOS?

Sorry for my bad English.
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible, the .so file is a binary and compiled for the x86 (x86_64) architecture.

iOS device run on an ARM architecture.